# Undefined variable: con Cannot fetch data from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

**index.php**

```
<?php include'includes/nav.php'; ?>
<?php include "includes/db.php"; ?>
```

**includes/nav.php**

```
<?php 
$allcategeories = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allcategeories ))
{
   echo "<li>{$row['cat_title']}</li>";
}
 ?>
```

**includes/db.php**

```
<?php
$db['DBhost'] = "localhost";
$db['DBuser'] = "root";
$db['DBpass'] = "";
$db['DBNAME'] = "cms";
foreach($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}
$con = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
if(!$con) {
    echo "cannot establish connection";
}
?>
```

**Errors**

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\includes\nav.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\includes\nav.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\includes\nav.php on line 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of including file in **index.php**

First you include your database file

```
<?php include "includes/db.php"; ?>
```

Then

```
<?php include'includes/nav.php'; ?>
```

Beacuse your database connection is defile in your `db.php` which include after `nav.php` that's you are getting undeine variable con